# node-mongodb-fixtures is not working with mongodb version 4

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am upgrading mongodb version from 3.14.4 to 4.0
I have upgraded node-mongodb-fixtures from 2.2.1 to 3.0.0 as well.

```
const fixture = new Fixtures({
                dir: 'fixtures/all',
                mute: true
            });
fixture.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testDb")
.then(() => fixture.unload())
.then(() => fixture.load())
.then(() => fixture.disconnect())
```

getting this error **mongodb database name must be a string**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing the the dbName in connection string, pass this as an option

```
fixtures.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017',options, dbName)
```

**connect(uri, options, dbName)**

For more info look at latest package: [node-mongodb-fixtures](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mongodb-fixtures)